# Banking software for the Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec

I have been looking for this for a long time but so far, I could not find any even barely usable banking software for the Mac. Do you know any?

I want to be able to browse, search and download my bank account data. Heck, even just importing it would be ok. Oh yeah, and if that would work with German banks would be great. But really, I just want to know if banking on the Mac is possible at all.

**Edit:** I tried iBank, Money, MoneyWell, MoneyDance, EasyMoney, Cha-Ching and Squirrel and talked to the customer support of Quicken Essentials. Some of them can at least partially import european/arbitrary CSV data, but none of them enough to make them useful.
(European transactions consist of a date, a payee bank number, a payee account number, a payee name, a receiver account number, two comment fields and of course the amount)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely take a look at [MoneyWell](http://nothirst.com/moneywell/). It does work automatically with some banks but not others depnding on whether the bank you are with allows downloading data in a standard format. Very highly rated by a number of people.

> MoneyWell™ gives you powerful personal finance organization and
>   analysis tools in a simple, single-screen solution. Without running
>   complex reports or having to trudge through six levels of pie charts,
>   you'll know immediately if your spending is on track.

[image]

Comment: That looks kinda nice. Except it crashes every two minutes…

Comment: Oh, and it can only partially import my data and the UI is constantly in inconsistent states (you can edit things that don't exist)… Oh my.

Comment: @Paperflyer I'd suggest you get in touch with the developer of MoneyWell. He is well known in the development community and if you are having all these problems I'm sure he's like to try and address them for you.

Comment: The thing is: European transaction data is just not compatible with American transaction data (there are more and different data fields). But I will talk to them.

Comment: I know the data used to be compatible with some UK banks but when the banks made some changes it broke the link. I think it does depnd on the bank somewhat.

Comment: Actually, I just talked to the devs of MoneyWell and they are right now implementing my required features, so I guess I just have to wait…

Answer (score 1):

Try [iBank](http://www.iggsoftware.com/ibank/).

> The Gold Standard for Mac money management. Monitor balances at a
>   glance, track investments, maintain budgets and manage accounts — all
>   in an easy, powerful, full-featured package.

[image]

Comment: It can't import the data from my bank. No use at all for me.